# ASP.NET MVC - How to use code first and database first method in same project and with same context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, transactionscope, ef-database-first

I have a requirement that I have to use code first pattern (which I have to implement) along with database first (which exists in the current system).

Now the condition is I must not create a different context for new tables or any other changes which I make in the database but have to maintain current context from DB first pattern. Is it possible to create code first and DB first in the same project sharing the same context? Do I must manage `.edmx` file or is it possible to handle the database from code first pattern only? And that too with managing `TransactionScope`.

I need some suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things that I learned from my above problem.

1. One cannot use the same context for Code first and Database first.
2. To use code first and database first in the same project, context must be different and irrespective of ConnectionString. (one can use either existing ConnectionString or make a new one)
3. It is not good practice to use two patterns at same, but if situation demands it, than one must have no choice. Therfore at last one can create POCO classes for code first, from database first so it can be useful.
4. TransactionScope be used with irrespective number of database connections and it will work properly.

If anything I am missing, than please add it so other can have better idea, or they could at least save their time.